# Quit browser in [AfterScenario]

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to learn C# and Selenium and for my first project I am trying to write the code for [BeforeScenario] and [AfterScenario]. I have manage to get the [BeforeScenario] working, however I am struggle to quit the browser in the [AfterScenario].

[BeforeScenario]

```
[BeforeScenario]
public void BeforeScenario()
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("--incognito");
    options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
    IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("URL");
}
```

[AfterScenario]

```
[AfterScenario]
public void AfterScenario()
{
    webDriver.Quit()
}
```

Why does my `webDriver.Quit()` always throw an error

Error on `webDriver`

'the name 'webDriver' does not exist in the current context'

New Code:

```
public class Steps
{
    public IWebDriver webDriver = null;

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        // BeforeScenario code
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("--incognito");
        options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
        IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://10.118.88.50");
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void AfterScenario()
    {
        // AfterScenario code
        if (webDriver == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Driver is null, call BeforeScenario() first.");
        }
        webDriver.Quit();
    }
```

After following the suggestions in the comment below now have the code above. The error has been removed, however when the code gets to AfterScenario it is always null. when the code is in BeforeScenario the webDriver is fine.

What am I missing here

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is?

Comment: seems like compiling error?

Comment: Variable visibility

Comment: I agree with Drag and Drop. You would need to declare webDriver at class level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the webDriver variable inside your BeforeScenario() function

```
IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

and when you use it in AfterScenario(), the function does not know what "webDriver" is. Make a class variable that can be accessed by both functions

```
public IWebDriver webDriver;
```

and initialize it in BeforeScenario so you can use it in AfterScenario.

A good thing is to initialize your webdriver in your class as null, so you can catch an exception if AfterScenario() is run before BeforeScenario(), like so:

```
public IWebDriver driver = null;

[BeforeScenario]
public void BeforeScenario()
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("--incognito");
    options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
    webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("URL");
}

[AfterScenario]
public void AfterScenario()
{
    if (driver == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Driver is null, call BeforeScenario() first.");
    }
    driver.Quit();
}
```

Comment: I used your code and it got rid of the error, however when the code is running AfterScenario, webDriver is always null.

Comment: @Ross is there any line of code in between BeforeScenario and AfterScenario that nulls the driver? In the test itself?

Comment: no I don't think so, the way I have pasted above is how it is in my code. this is using Gherkin script to create scenario. could the scenario make the driver null?

Comment: I have no idea how Gherkin script works, but can you maybe debug the scenario and see where the driver becomes null? Maybe go to the start of the scenario code and do
    IWebDriver testDriver1 = driver;
so you can see when debugging if the driver is ok, and at the end of your test, do it one more time 
IWebDriver testDriver2 = driver;
and see if it's null there, maybe the driver becomes null even before reaching AfterScenario.